# AS3 fullscreen delay in chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, fullscreen, delay, stagedisplaystate

How can I hide all controls before stageDisplayState changes?
`setTimeout` and `Timer` cannot be used to delay switching to fullscreen.
I have created a curtain element that I want to show BEFORE the display state change. 
Timeout, timers, and mousedown events do not give any change events in my application, so what can I do?

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (e:MouseEvent):void {

    //curtain shows AFTER enter to fullscreen mode - must before
    curtain.visible = true;
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
});
```

Any tips, dear ActionScript masters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this.
You can only enter full screen mode in response to a user click ([Adobe: working with full-screen mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html)).

So if you pause to do any animation or screen updating, you are no longer responding *directly* to a user click.

The only thing you could do would be to animate on the curtain and then throw up another button for the user to click to *really* enter full screen. That's not a very elegant solution though.